# return a value from a class method in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, function, class

I have created a class method called **quantityMethod** and I am calling it inside a function.

I have created an if-else and want to call the function for each condition.

Here's my Typescript code:

```ts
let quantity: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.createElement("input");
quantity.type = "number"
quantity.id = "quan"
document.body.appendChild(quantity)
    
var Mahindra: Car = new Car(1, "Mahindra chhota", 80000);
var Jaguar: Car = new Car(2,"Jaguar Big",90000);
var getQuantity: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("quan");
var gQ = getQuantity.value;
var btn: HTMLButtonElement = <HTMLButtonElement>document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "Get Quantity"
document.body.appendChild(btn)

let ID = +Id.value
if (ID == 1) {
    Mahindra.display();
}
else if(ID == 2) {
    Jaguar.display();
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    Mahindra.quantityMethod(+getQuantity.value)
})
```

Here's the method in my class **Curve**:

```ts
quantityMethod(gQ: number) {
    Display.innerHTML += "<br>"+"The Quantity selected is " + gQ + 
                         " and the total cost is "+gQ*this.price;
}
display() {
    Display.innerHTML = "The id of the car is " + this.id + 
                        " and the model selected is " + this.model + 
                        "  " + " It's price is "+this.price;
}
```

I am getting the ID from an input box and if the ID satisfies any one of the condition, I will enter the quantity in the newly generated input box and on clicking, display the quantity and cost of that particular id.

How do I do that?

**btn.addEventListener** has only Mahindra.

Comment: to return a value from any method, use `return someValue`

Answer (score 0):

You already suggested an answer in the question

```
quantityMethod(gQ: number) {
        Display.innerHTML += "<br>"+"The Quantity selected is " + gQ+" and the total cost is "+gQ*this.price;
      return += "<br>"+"The Quantity selected is " + gQ+" and the total cost is "+gQ*this.price;
    }
```

Comment: If I click on the button, I will get the quantity only for Mahindra. I want it to be applicable on Jaguar too

Comment: check your condition or share entire code. because i can see few typo.. like `elseif` will have space like this `else if`